# What is a more efficient way to load 1 column with 1 000 000+ rows than pandas read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to import large files (.tab/.txt, 300+ columns and 1 000 000+ rows) in Python. The file are tab seperated. The columns are filled with integer values. One of my goals is to make a sum of each column. However, the files are too large to import with `pandas.read_csv()` as it consumes too much RAM. 
sample data:

[image]

Therefore I wrote following code to import 1 column, perform the sum of that column, store the result in a dataframe (= summed_cols), delete the column, and go on with the next column of the file:

```
x=10 ###columns I'm interested in start at col 11

#empty dataframe to fill
summed_cols=pd.DataFrame(columns=["sample","read sum"])

while x<352:
    x=x+1
    sample_col=pd.read_csv("file.txt",sep="\t",usecols=[x])
    summed_cols=summed_cols.append(pd.DataFrame({"sample":[sample_col.columns[0]],"read sum":sum(sample_col[sample_col.columns[0]])}))
    del sample_col
```

Each column represents a sample and the ''read sum'' is the sum of that column. So the output of this code is a dataframe with 2 columns with in the first column one sample per row, and in the second column the corresponding read sum.

This code does exactly what I want to do, however, it is not efficient. For this large file it takes about 1-2 hours to complete the calculations. Especially the loading of just 1 columns takes quiet a long time.

**My question:** Is there a faster way to import just one column of this large tab file and perform the same calculations as I'm doing with the code above?

Comment: why don't use pandas inbuilt sum function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414960/how-do-i-create-a-sum-row-and-sum-column-in-pandas

Comment: I am not sure if it will be faster, but if you need only the column sum wouldn't be easier to just read the file with python, line by line, and accumulate the sum?

Comment: @manishPrasad That is not really what I'm looking for and if you check my code you can see I use the ```sum() function```. I don't see how your comment would answer my question to be honest.

Comment: @alec_djinn That sounds interesting and it basically should work and is worth the try. Could you provide me some code to do this? (I'm rather new in Python)

Comment: @Robvh Built in function of data frame would be much faster than the sum function sample_cols['amount'].sum()

Comment: @Robvh I think the problem here is that the OP is opening the file and generating a DataFrame at every iteration. It is true that pandas built in `sum()` is faster. But in this case, it would not help much. The code needs a complete redesign.

Comment: Yes the sum function is not the time consumer/bottleneck in this code, but the iteration and creation of each column is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
samples = []
sums = []

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        columns = line.strip().split('\t')[10:] #from column 10 onward
        if i == 0: #supposing the sample_name is the first row of each column
            samples = columns #save sample names
            sums = [0 for s in samples] #init the sums to 0
        else:
            for n,v in enumerate(columns):
                sums[n] += float(v)

result = dict(zip(samples,sums)) #{sample_name:sum, ...}
```

I am not sure this will work since I don't know the content of your input file but it describes the general procedure. You open the file only once, you iterate over each line, split to get the columns, and store the data you need.
Mind that this code does not deal with missing values.

The `else` block can be improved using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
...
else:
    sums = np.add(sums, map(float,columns))
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! I will try it soon. I hope I'm not asking too much of you, but could you add comments after each line? As I'm relatively new to Python I can't follow the code for a 100% and I'd like to learn as much as possible.

Comment: @Robvh I have commented on what is necessary. The code is quite readable what is not clear?

Comment: Yes your code is not the problem, but my python knowledge is. I don't get ```sums = [0 for s in samples]``` and ```for n,v in enumerate(columns): sums[n] += float(v)```. Could you perhaps clarify a bit more in your post?

Comment: Check this https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python and this https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: I just tried the code and it seems to work! It is A LOT faster than my original code. Where my code runs 1-2 hours, yours performed the calculations in 1 minute or so. Very impressive that you can write the code so efficient. Now the ''results'' variable is a dictionary and appears to have a ```type``` and ```size``` "column" which are float and 1 respectively for every row. What are this type and size and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Dictionaries have key:value pairs, not columns. in your case the dict should be something like {'sample1':123, 'sample2':99, ...}   `type` and `size` are keys or values? If you can input 2-3 lines of your input file I can fix the code accordingly, not knowing the file format it's not feasible.

Comment: I made an attempt to add a table of 2 lines of sample data. The first 10 columns and the columns after the last sample column are other parameters which are unimportant for the analysis.

Comment: That is not the actuall file content. Are you on a Mac or Linux system? If so, in the terminal type `less file.txt` and please copy-paste the output.

Comment: Anyway, it's clear you have a header. I have modified the code to deal with it. Try it and let me know please.

Comment: The new code you provided does not work. Something is wrong with the key:value pairs now. Output: ```{'6046': 848883.0,
 '5364': 213764.0,
 '7': 466462.0,
 '3249': 89579.0,
 '108196': 6697141.0,
 '652643': 5100875.0,
 '112523': 1382025.0,.....```

Comment: Please shom me the output of the previous code. I have reverted the last modifications.

Comment: Ah damn I am so sorry. Your previous code was correct....... :\ I just recently started  working in Spyder and when I clicked the variable in the variable explorer it showed two extra "columns" there but when I print ```result``` it is just fine. Sorry for this mistake..

Comment: Well, it's ok. The answer is valid anyway as a general approach. You have a working code, that's all it matters.

Comment: One more question, why in ```columns = line.strip().split('\t')[10:]```, why do you add ```.strip()``` ? It has no argument and I ran it with and without ```.strip()``` and there seems to be no difference.

Comment: Just a precaution. `strip()` will remove any white-spaces or newline chars that may appear at the end of one line, if there are no white spaces, it doesn't modify anything.