# Inefficient code in python allocates to much memory

Tags: python, memory

I am trying to manipulate some data and put it in a dataframe. The initial dataframe is already stored in 29 dataframes with 300 (columns) x 800000 (rows), as it could not be handled in one dataframe with my ressources.

Now I want to store the data in 3 dataframes and through the operation I am reducing the overall data to a third (building the average over three columns).

It ran once and when running it twice I am always getting memory errors. I already changed the intermediate data storage from list to numpy array. But I think my code is somehow inefficient in allocating the memory and seems to block it also after running the code. Restarting python helps, but is not really a long term solution, as I also want to do some more operations on the data frames.

See my code for reference:

```
df_consolidated_1= pd.DataFrame()
df_consolidated_2= pd.DataFrame()
df_consolidated_3= pd.DataFrame()

lst_intermediate=np.array([])

i=0
for j in range (0,10):
    k=0
    while k < 300:
        lst_intermediate=    
        (dfs[j].iloc[:,k]+dfs[j].iloc[:,k+1]+dfs[j].iloc[:,k+2])/3
        df_consolidated_1[i]=lst_intermediate
        i+=1
        k+=3        
for j in range (11,20):
    k=0
    while k < 300:
        lst_intermediate= 
        dfs[j].iloc[:,k]+dfs[j].iloc[:,k+1]+dfs[j].iloc[:,k+2])/3
        df_consolidated_2[i]=lst_intermediate
        i+=1
        k+=3
for j in range (20,29):
    k=0
    while k < 300:
        lst_intermediate= 
        dfs[j].iloc[:,k]+dfs[j].iloc[:,k+1]+dfs[j].iloc[:,k+2])/3
        df_consolidated_3[i]=lst_intermediate
        i+=1
        k+=3
```

Comment: You could try to read your initial dataframe using ```with open() as file:``` check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open. This should significantly reduce the memory use. Somewhat similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685597/what-is-a-more-efficient-way-to-load-1-column-with-1-000-000-rows-than-pandas-r