# sum a list in each dataframes row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to sum 'list' in each row in pandas dataframe. How do I do that?

```
row   list
(1)     [1,2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
(2)     [2, 4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
(3)     [7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1, 0.0, 0.0]
(4)     [2, 0.0, 9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
(5)     [3, 4, 5, 3, 0.0, 0]
```

I would like the output to be:

```
row   list
(1)     3
(2)     6
(3)     8
(4)     2
(5)     15
```

I tried many `dataframe.sum(),` they just would not work.

For example:

1. `df['list'].sum(axis=1)`
2. `df['list'].sum()`

The results:

1. ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type
2. would get me sum of five rows lists values into one list.

Comment: `df['list'].apply(sum)` ?

Comment: Try this `df['list'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with casting to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['list'] = df['list'].apply(sum).astype(int)
print (df)
   row  list
0  (1)     3
1  (2)     6
2  (3)     8
3  (4)    11
4  (5)    15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
df['list'] = df['list'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
```

If you want to have an `int`, you should cast the sum:

```
df['list'] = df['list'].apply(lambda x: int(sum(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
#Total sum per row:
df.loc[:,'Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414960/how-do-i-create-a-sum-row-and-sum-column-in-pandas](http://another%20SO%20answer)

Comment: the code also return this error. No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>