# If there a Python function to sum all of the columns of a particular row? If not, what would be the best way to go about this?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If there a Python function to sum all of the squares of the columns of a particular row? If not, what would be the best way to go about this?

e.g.,

If someone's age is 50, height is 70, and weight is 176, I would want 50^{2} + 70^{2} + 176^{2}

Comment: It is definitely possible & definitely been answered before. Please search for this question. `sum(axis=1)` should do the trick

Comment: You can also do `.iloc[index].sum()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414960/how-do-i-create-a-sum-row-and-sum-column-in-pandas

Comment: @rdas sorry I guess I should have specified more (I'll edit the question). Is there a way to add the squares of each column?

Comment: @SH-SF just edited the question. Sorry for the vagueness. Could I square the entries as I go along each column?

Comment: @324 Try `(df.iloc[index]**2).sum()`

Comment: @324 try `np.square(df).sum(axis=1)`