# Pandas: sum rows of random numbers

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.8

I have the following code that makes a 100x100 dataframe of random integers:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bin = []
cols = []
for i in range(1,101):
    cols.append("count_" + str(i))
    bin.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(100, 100)), index=bin, columns=cols)

    count_1  count_2  count_3  ... count_100
1   1        3        6        ... 9
2   2        8        4        ... 7
... ...      ...      ...      ... ...
100 6        3        8        ... 2
```

If I want the sum of the columns, I can use:

```
df.sum()
```

to give me

```
count_1      516
count_2      505
count_3      503
            ... 
count_98     534
count_99     489
count_100    521
```

but I would like the sum of the rows. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I believe you can pass the axis into sum

Comment: try this: `df.sum(1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a sum row and sum column in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414960/how-do-i-create-a-sum-row-and-sum-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`df.sum(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas-dataframe-sum)

> ```
> DataFrame.sum(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, min_count=0, **kwargs)`
> ```
>
> Return the sum of the values over the
> requested axis.
>
> This is equivalent to the method `numpy.sum`.
>
> Parameters `axis{index (0), columns (1)}`: **Axis for the function to be applied on**.

Answer (score 0):

```
bin = []
cols = []
for i in range(1,21):
   cols.append("count_" + str(i))
   bin.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(20, 20)), index=bin, columns=cols)
for col in cols:
    df[col]=df[col].astype(int) 

print(df.head())

fig,ax =plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
for item in df[cols].sum():
    print(item)
grouped=df[cols].sum().plot(kind='barh')


###########how to sum each row###########

df['sum']=0
for key,item in df.iterrows():
    sum=0
    for col in cols:
        sum+=df.loc[key,col]
    df.loc[key,'sum']=sum

 print (df.head())
```

Comment: Did you read the question? "But I need the sum of rows". Also using `for` with pandas is discouraged and should be the last option.

Comment: the plot visual shows the result  of the column summaries.  See matplotlib and read about groupby and aggregates

Comment: I can't see how `df[cols].sum()` can make sum in rows, it is apparetly going through cols. With 100x100 df yes you might have a feeling it is by rows as there is same count, but try with 2 cols 100 rows and you get 2 results, one for each column.

Comment: Yes exactly, feature type = column. Row = one record of different columns. OP told in question they know how to get count by columns, they need it by row. I think it is clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227717/discussion-between-ruli-and-golden-lion).

Comment: no need.  I added the code to sum it row. It was beginner level code.