# Calculated gainers and decliners

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use a Pandas DataFrame of which I will show a small section below and I want to add 5 new rows to the bottom for each of the tickers

Row 1:  the number of gainers (> 0).

Row 2: the number of decliners (<0).

Row 3:The geometric average of gainers (gainers * gainers) ^ (1 / number of gainers).

Row 4:The geometric average of decliners (decliners * decliners) ^ (1 / number of decliners).

Row 5: Relative strength index = 100 - (100 / (1 + (geometric average gainers / geometric average decliners))

| Date | AGN.AS | AH.AS | MT.AS | RDSA.AS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2-2-2021 00:00 | 0.025925 | 0.005716 | -0.009999 | 0.002519 |
| 3-2-2021 00:00 | -0.000568 | -0.000765 | -0.009331 | 0.015077 |
| 4-2-2021 00:00 | 0.022727 | 0.00525 | 0.015847 | -0.015375 |
| 5-2-2021 00:00 | 0.0075 | 0.000979 | 0.01669 | 0.029509 |
| 8-2-2021 00:00 | 0.012407 | 0.005 | 0.027897 | 0.006684 |

What is the best practice to solve such an iterative calculation?

These two work perfectly fine:
`df.loc["gainers", :] = df[df>0].count(axis=0)` `df.loc["decliners",:] = df[df<0].count(axis=0)`

But these:
`df.loc["geogainers",:] = df[df>0].multiply(axis=0)`
`df.loc["geodecliners",:] = df[df<0].multiply(axis=0)`

Give the following error:
`TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'`

Comment: What have you tried? Why did it fail?

Comment: I get stuck at:
`code` df.loc['gainers'] =

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414960/how-do-i-create-a-sum-row-and-sum-column-in-pandas) for an example of how to create new rows/columns and fill them with aggregate values. So, one way to determine the first variable would be `df.loc["gainers", :] = df[df>0].count(axis=0)`. Now you just have to figure out the rest of the formulas.

Comment: Thank you! I have been struggling with this one for ages. Long live Mr. T

Comment: `df.loc["geogainers",:] = df[df>0].multiply(axis=0)`
 Results in:
`TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'`